# Gearman client does not run

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, distributed-computing, gearman

I have been able to successfully install gearman on an Amazon AWS server as well as the PHP extension for gearman. I run my setup in the following steps :

1. Start gearmand server
2. Run the worker and wait for jobs
3. Run the client and send jobs to the server

However, the process does not work. I think this is getting stuck at the gearman client. Below is my simple code for client, server and worker (along with the log file output and execution output)

**Client Code :**

```
<?php

$client = new GearmanClient();
$client->addServer('localhost', 4730);

$arguments = array(
    'url' => 'http://localhost/hit.php',
);

$client->addTask('fetchURL', json_encode($arguments));

print "running tasks";

if(!$client->runTasks())
{
    echo "ERROR " . $client->error() . "\n";
    exit;
}
else
    print "task done";

echo "DONE";
```

**Worker Code :**

```
<?php
$worker = new GearmanWorker();
$worker->addServer("localhost", 4730);
$worker->addFunction("fetchURL", "fetch_url");

print "Waiting for job...\n";
while($worker->work())
{
  if ($worker->returnCode() != GEARMAN_SUCCESS)
  {
    echo "return_code: " . $worker->returnCode() . "\n";
    break;
  }
}

function fetch_url($job)
{
    print "function called...\n";
    $arguments = json_decode($job->workload(),TRUE);

    if (!empty($arguments['url']))
    {
        print("Fetching " . $arguments['url'] . "\n");
        return file_get_contents($arguments['url']);
    }
}
```

**Server output :**

[image]

**Worker output :**

[image]

**Client output :**

[image]

**Log file output :**

```
DEBUG 2016-09-02 12:06:38.848867 [  main ] THREADS: 4 -> libgearman-server/gearmand.cc:263
   INFO 2016-09-02 12:06:38.848911 [  main ] Initializing Gear on port 4730 with SSL: false
   INFO 2016-09-02 12:06:38.848956 [  main ] Starting up with pid 28079, verbose is set to DEBUG
  DEBUG 2016-09-02 12:06:38.848997 [  main ] Method for libevent: epoll -> libgearman-server/gearmand.cc:362
  DEBUG 2016-09-02 12:06:38.849036 [  main ] Trying to listen on 127.0.0.1:4730 -> libgearman-server/gearmand.cc:639
   INFO 2016-09-02 12:06:38.849056 [  main ] Listening on 127.0.0.1:4730 (9)
  DEBUG 2016-09-02 12:06:38.849064 [  main ] Creating wakeup pipe -> libgearman-server/gearmand.cc:903
  DEBUG 2016-09-02 12:06:38.849069 [  main ] Creating 4 threads -> libgearman-server/gearmand.cc:376
  DEBUG 2016-09-02 12:06:38.849076 [  main ] Initializing libevent for IO thread -> libgearman-server/gearmand_thread.cc:207
  DEBUG 2016-09-02 12:06:38.849090 [  main ] Creating IO thread wakeup pipe -> libgearman-server/gearmand_thread.cc:478
  DEBUG 2016-09-02 12:06:38.849119 [  main ] Thread 1 created -> libgearman-server/gearmand_thread.cc:256
  DEBUG 2016-09-02 12:06:38.849149 [  main ] Initializing libevent for IO thread -> libgearman-server/gearmand_thread.cc:207
  DEBUG 2016-09-02 12:06:38.849164 [  main ] Creating IO thread wakeup pipe -> libgearman-server/gearmand_thread.cc:478
  DEBUG 2016-09-02 12:06:38.849183 [  main ] Thread 2 created -> libgearman-server/gearmand_thread.cc:256
  DEBUG 2016-09-02 12:06:38.849189 [  main ] Initializing libevent for IO thread -> libgearman-server/gearmand_thread.cc:207
  DEBUG 2016-09-02 12:06:38.849206 [  main ] Creating IO thread wakeup pipe -> libgearman-server/gearmand_thread.cc:478
  DEBUG 2016-09-02 12:06:38.849225 [  main ] Thread 3 created -> libgearman-server/gearmand_thread.cc:256
  DEBUG 2016-09-02 12:06:38.849230 [  main ] Initializing libevent for IO thread -> libgearman-server/gearmand_thread.cc:207
  DEBUG 2016-09-02 12:06:38.849245 [  main ] Creating IO thread wakeup pipe -> libgearman-server/gearmand_thread.cc:478
  DEBUG 2016-09-02 12:06:38.849268 [  main ] Thread 4 created -> libgearman-server/gearmand_thread.cc:256
  DEBUG 2016-09-02 12:06:38.849273 [  main ] replaying queue: begin -> libgearman-server/gearmand.cc:389
  DEBUG 2016-09-02 12:06:38.849276 [  main ] __replay -> libgearman-server/plugins/queue/default/queue.cc:101
  DEBUG 2016-09-02 12:06:38.849279 [  main ] replaying queue: end -> libgearman-server/gearmand.cc:395
   INFO 2016-09-02 12:06:38.849282 [  main ] Adding event for listening socket (9)
  DEBUG 2016-09-02 12:06:38.849285 [  main ] Adding event for wakeup pipe -> libgearman-server/gearmand.cc:956
  DEBUG 2016-09-02 12:06:38.849288 [  main ] Entering main event loop -> libgearman-server/gearmand.cc:404
  DEBUG 2016-09-02 12:06:38.849336 [     2 ] Entering thread event loop -> libgearman-server/gearmand_thread.cc:446
  DEBUG 2016-09-02 12:06:38.849361 [     3 ] Entering thread event loop -> libgearman-server/gearmand_thread.cc:446
  DEBUG 2016-09-02 12:06:38.849379 [     4 ] Entering thread event loop -> libgearman-server/gearmand_thread.cc:446
  DEBUG 2016-09-02 12:06:38.849412 [     1 ] Entering thread event loop -> libgearman-server/gearmand_thread.cc:446
  DEBUG 2016-09-02 12:06:38.849422 [  main ] staring up Epoch thread -> libgearman-server/timer.cc:61




  DEBUG 2016-09-02 12:06:38.855568 [  main ] accept() 32 -> libgearman-server/gearmand.cc:862
   INFO 2016-09-02 12:06:38.855580 [  main ] Accepted connection from 127.0.0.1:33071
  DEBUG 2016-09-02 12:06:38.855593 [     4 ] Received CON wakeup event -> libgearman-server/gearmand_thread.cc:605
  DEBUG 2016-09-02 12:06:38.855602 [     4 ] setsockopt() fd:32 -> libgearman-server/io.cc:833
  DEBUG 2016-09-02 12:06:38.855613 [     4 ]       127.0.0.1:33071 Watching  POLLIN  -> libgearman-server/gearmand_thread.cc:151

  DEBUG 2016-09-02 12:09:30.885913 [  main ] accept() 33 -> libgearman-server/gearmand.cc:862
   INFO 2016-09-02 12:09:30.885943 [  main ] Accepted connection from 127.0.0.1:33073
  DEBUG 2016-09-02 12:09:30.885969 [     3 ] Received CON wakeup event -> libgearman-server/gearmand_thread.cc:605
  DEBUG 2016-09-02 12:09:30.885983 [     3 ] setsockopt() fd:33 -> libgearman-server/io.cc:833
  DEBUG 2016-09-02 12:09:30.885993 [     3 ]       127.0.0.1:33073 Watching  POLLIN  -> libgearman-server/gearmand_thread.cc:151


  DEBUG 2016-09-02 12:09:34.144611 [  main ] accept() 34 -> libgearman-server/gearmand.cc:862
   INFO 2016-09-02 12:09:34.144634 [  main ] Accepted connection from 127.0.0.1:33075
  DEBUG 2016-09-02 12:09:34.144650 [     2 ] Received CON wakeup event -> libgearman-server/gearmand_thread.cc:605
  DEBUG 2016-09-02 12:09:34.144662 [     2 ] setsockopt() fd:34 -> libgearman-server/io.cc:833
  DEBUG 2016-09-02 12:09:34.144673 [     2 ]       127.0.0.1:33075 Watching  POLLIN  -> libgearman-server/gearmand_thread.cc:151
```

I have put line spaces in the logs to denote the points from where the worker starts & the client starts. From the logs, it looks like the client is also behaving like a worker (or a worker like a client) as there seems to be no difference between the log transactions for worker or client. I'm not sure whether the log transactions are supposed to be more clearer but this seems odd to me.

Also, my gearman client does not exit. which is weird.

Nothing happens after this. Am I going wrong somewhere ? This is the collective understanding I have had from reading multiple tutorials available about gearman online however I still can't get it to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve the problem. It was as simple as changing localhost to 127.0.0.1 in the client.php and worker.php

Not sure why, but this worked. If anyone has an explanation for this, I would be happy to know :)

Comment: The addServer() method appears to only work with IP addresses.  You could add code to 'ping' the job server to see if it responds and fail gracefully if it doesn't.  See http://php.net/manual/en/gearmanworker.echo.php and http://php.net/manual/en/gearmanclient.ping.php